# How is marriage after divorce looked upon?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, marriage

From this [article](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/whatbudbeliev/237.htm), it is clear that Buddhism accepts(but doesn't really root for it) divorce when things get worse.  But, how is marriage after divorce looked upon?

Comment: The first paragraph of that article says that Buddhism has no religious rules about even the first marriage. So perhaps it's only individual Buddhists or specific Buddhist societies who might "look upon" marriage after divorce. If this is a question about the social conventions of Buddhist societies perhaps it would be better to identify which society (e.g. which nationality) you're asking about.

Comment: @ChrisW Tibetean Buddhism.  Added the relevant tag

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd precept doesn't prevent you from getting remarried. So as long as you don't steal another man's wife, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As not learning from your mistake.

Just kidding. :)

No problem at all. From the same article mentioned:

> The Buddhist views on marriage are very liberal: in Buddhism, marriage
>   is regarded entirely as personal and individual concern, and not as a
>   religious duty. There are no religious laws in Buddhism compelling a
>   person to be married, to remain as a bachelor or to lead a life of
>   total chastity. It is not laid down anywhere that Buddhists must
>   produce children or regulate the number of children that they produce.
>   **Buddhism allows each individual the freedom to decide for himself all
>   the issues pertaining to marriage.**

Although this is the author's interpretation or opinion, I didn't find anywhere in the article that mentioned that remarrying is looked down upon. I don't know of any teachings related to this either.